# Django Form: Calling foreign key field attributes in template

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys, class-attributes

In a template I want to call a class attributes of a foreign-key form field *item.pid* like shown below

```html
{%for item in form.item %}
{{item.pid}}
{% endfor %}
```

My question is simple and the solution should be as well but I am stuck here for way too long now. I have tried formsets, inlineformsets, clean and so many more things which are in the documentation and here on SO.
It's even not possible to call a class method of a form field.

calling *{{form.instance.item.pid}}* should be the solution but I can't get it running.

**model.py**

```py
class Event(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=0)
#many more

class Person(models.Model):
    person_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
#many more

class Item(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=0)
    pid = models.IntegerField(null=True) 
#many more

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        self.pid = Person.objects.filter(surname=self.person.surname, name=self.person.name).values("person_number")
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**views.py**

```py
def event(request, event_id=None):

    if event_id:
        instance = get_object_or_404(Event, pk=event_id)
    else:
        instance = Event()
   
    form = EventForm(request.POST or None, instance=instance)    

    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cal:calendar'))
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }    
    return render(request, 'cal/event.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```py
class EventForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Event

    fields = ('person', 'item', 'manymore',)
```

Comment: What's the purpose of displaying that information? The `Item` field of an `Event` form (by default) will let you choose between different items. But you can change the way those choices are rendered if that's what you want.

Comment: I am making choices depending on item.pid and person.person_number.
for example to create a chained dropdown selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customise the choices of your FK fields is fairly simple.

I've done this just a few hours back and I do it using a cached method so that the database isn't hit to generate the list each time.

So I have a `Currency` table and I wanted to allow an applicant choose a currency related to their application;

```
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """ Application form """

    currency = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=[]
    )

    class Meta:
        """ Setup the form """
        fields = (
            ...
            'currency',
            ...
        )
        model = Application

    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['currency'].choices = get_currency_choices()

    def clean(self):
        """
        Custom form cleaning
        """
        cleaned_data = super().clean()

        currency_id = cleaned_data.get('currency')
        cleaned_data['currency'] = Currency.objects.get(id=currency_id)
```

So as you can see in this form, the `currency` field is getting it's choices from `get_currency_choices`. For a ForeignKey you also need to have an instance of the related model to save that relationship, so in the `clean` I get the instance related to the choice by the ID which is the value of the field in the form.

The choices are generated from the related model and stored in the cache with the following method;

```py
def get_currency_choices():
    """ Get currency choices, from cache if possible """
    currency_choices = cache.get(CACHED_CURRENCY_KEY)
    if not currency_choices:
        currencies = Currency.objects.values('id', 'symbol', 'code')
        currency_choices = list()
        currency_choices.append((None, ''))  # I use this so that there isn't a default choice & people can't make the wrong choice by leaving the default value.
        for currency in currencies:
            currency_choices.append(
                (currency['id'], f"{currency['symbol']} ({currency['code']})")
            )
        cache.set(
            CACHED_CURRENCY_KEY, currency_choices, CACHED_CURRENCY_LENGTH
        )
    return currency_choices
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time. 

Implemented your code and I am getting two outcomes:

__1.__ forms.py Meta is defined like in my example: code runs but ```currency.id``` (my case: item.pid) returns nothing. calling item is fine and returns ```__str__```

__2.__ forms.py Meta is defined your way returns: ```Exception Value: 
name 'get_item_choices' is not defined```
...
I've tried putting get_item_choices to Event Class' as well as to Item Class' model

Comment: update: I went on with __2.__ from my above post and put the method directly into ```__init__```. The appended ```currency_choices```are being shown in template now. This makes me wonder if all the solutions I tried didn't work, because my ```forms.py``` is wrong... ps: an append doesn't allow to use ```currency.id```in the code, correct?

Comment: If you've got `get_item_choices is not defined` you just need to include that function before your form, or import it from another place at the top of your forms file. Doing this will allow you to just include that field as `{{ form.item }}` or however you wish to display the form. You don't need to iterate over anything. Just make sure the way you want to display it is generated by that choices function.

Comment: I am obviously doing something wrong. Your ```get_item_choices``` as well as the following solutions are running but all I get is ```__str__``` or one the last field like ```doi```. Looping through form.item returns nothing as soon as I add ```*.pid``` or ```*.doi```. Wrong loop?  

```test = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[]) | def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['test'].choices = list(Item.objects.values_list('pid', 'doi'))``` or

```test = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all())```

Comment: less blabla: looping in template through your code returns the part in  ```f" ({tata['doi']})"``` my loop is ```{% for p in form.test %} {{p}}{% endfor %}``` while ```{{p.pid}}```does nothing

Comment: Your choices need to be a list of tuples `(item.pid, item.doi) for item in Item.objects.all()`. That would give you a select box to choose from the `doi` and the `pid` would be the value used by the form when saving.